# Double all the numbers in a string using python

Tags: python, regex

I want to double all the numbers that appear before px or pt in a string. Here is what I did so far:

```
s = """
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
bbb {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
bbb {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
"""
pat = re.compile(r"(.*?)(\d+)(pt|px)(.*?)", re.DOTALL)
mat = pat.findall(s)
myout = []
for tupleiter in mat:
    listiter = list(tupleiter)
    number = int(float(listiter[1]))
    number = 2 * number
    listiter[1] = str(number)
    myout.append("".join(listiter))
myout = "".join(myout)
print(s)
print(myout)
```

The problem with this approach is the non-matching part at the end will be ignored:

```
print(s)
111 {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
222 {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
bbb {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}

print(myout)
111 {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-top: 22px;
}
222 {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-top: 22px
```

I wonder how this can be done properly.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Celeo He wants to figure out how to make the last part match.

Comment: Yeah, I want to modify these numbers, but leave everything else intact, too.

Answer (score 3):

You're better off using `re.sub` with a callable to do the replacement, eg:

```
import re
new = re.sub('(\d+)(px|pt)', lambda m: str(int(m.group(1)) * 2) + m.group(2), s)
```

Gives you:

```
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-top: 22px;
}
bbb {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-top: 22px;
}
bbb {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using re.split

```
import re

print "".join([str(int(p)*2) if p.isdigit() else p 
                for p in re.split("(\d+)(px|pt)", s)])
```

[See the code in action: **repl.it**](http://repl.it/2kS)

#### Result

```
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-top: 22px;
}
bbb {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
aaa {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-top: 22px;
}
bbb {
    icon-size: 1.25em;
}
```